# Field evaluation during object creation

Tags: javascript, object, initialization

I need to create object in JavaScript but during object initialization some field of object should be evaluated.

For example in Python I could do this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.b = []
        for i in range(6):
            self.b.append(a * i)

a = A(3)
print(a.b)  # [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

But when I tried similar code in JavaScript, it doesn't work

```
function A (a){
    this.b = []; 
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        this.b.push(a * i);
    }
}

a = A(3);
console.log(a.b); // no results
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jf6txec1/

How could I perform some evaluation during object initialization in JavaScript?

Comment: `let a = new A(3);
console.log(a.b);`

Comment: You can also just use regular variable in the function and return an object with something like `return {b: b}` You won't need the `new` in that case.

Comment: thank you. as long time I used Python I forgot about 'new' keyword.